# Chilkat IPhone Libraries Configuration

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4.2, chilkat

I am working RSA Encryption-Decryption in iphone by Chilkat-9.3.0-IOS-4.3 Objective-C Libraries. I try to follow this tutorial http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatIos.asp but the first command "libtool -static -o libchilkatIos.a libDevice/libchilkatIos.a libSimulator/libchilkatIos.a" not working for me. 
Result of this command like :libtool: for architecture: armv6 file: libDevice/libchilkatIos.a(ChilkatBzip2_ppmd.o) has no symbols
same like these many "no symbol"

I want to use Chilkat in to my project Please guide me.
Thanks

Comment: Hi Amir, did you find out what caused your error?